# Same font in different pages of a site taken in same browser renders differently

Tags: css, fonts, rendering

I have a `"font-family: PT Sans;"` applied to span element but the text in it renders differently in different pages in the same browser itself. In home page, it renders the `"Arial"` font styles but in login page, it is something else. I have tried to fix it by giving `"font-family: Arial;"` to the span and then it renders same across all the pages.

Why is it different for the first `font-family` and is it the correct fix?

Can anyone help??

This is the styles applied to the span with class name "manageListing":

```
.manageListing {
width: 133px;
height: 21px;
padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
display: block;
text-align: center;
font-family: PT Sans;
font-size: 14px;
color: #ffffff;
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
-ms-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px rgba(50, 50, 46, 0.28);
-moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px rgba(50, 50, 46, 0.28);
box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px rgba(50, 50, 46, 0.28);
-ms-box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px rgba(50, 50, 46, 0.28);    
}
```

Comment: You could take a look into the dev tools and examine by which style yours gets overridden. By the way have you styled the span element with font-family: PT Sans. As a first step just give the specific span a class name and apply the PT Sans part to that specific class name in your css

Comment: Yes Somesh, i have given the span a class name and added styles to it and tried.

Comment: Side note - Since there is a space shouldn't you be setting as `font-family: 'PT Sans'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`font-family: PT Sans` used in the css file is a google font, imported from fonts.googleapis.com and the issue was due to protocol `(http)` added to the full url in css file to import the google font. So, the pages where url has secure protocol was not getting the `font-family: PT Sans;`and pages where url is not secure was getting the correct google font. So i modified `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans);` in css file to `@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans);` and it solved the issue.
Thanks for all who tried to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It must be inheriting a font from elsewhere. Stick an "!important" after "PT Sans" and it will  take that value rather than the inherited one.

Comment: It is not fixing the problem and still renders differently.

Comment: Just throwing around `!important` does will solve a short-term problem, but will give you headaches in the future. Do not use them unless you have no alternative. It is preferable to up the specificity so your rule wins.

Comment: Thank you Ruskin for the feedback.